# How to move the button with the sidebar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing a college project about a personal website and I need some help to make the Button move alongside the sidebar.

The sidebar moves to the right if you click on the hamburger menu and back if you do the same. In that case, the `active` class is being toggled. My problem is that my introductory accordion and its description text is not positioned and moving in a manner that's consistent with the sidebar.

I'm a beginner in this subject and I'm trying my best to get a good grade for this project, as you can see, I have put a page and design together.

```js
function show() {
  document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('active');
}
document.querySelectorAll('.accordion__button').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const accordionContent = button.nextElementSibling;
    button.classList.toggle('accordion__button--active');
    if (button.classList.contains('accordion__button--active')) {
      accordionContent.style.maxHeight = accordionContent.scrollHeight + 'px';

    } else {
      accordionContent.style.maxHeight = 0;
    }
  })
})
```

```css
#rcorners1 {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #222222;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  background-color: #222222;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  color: #EFDC75;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  left: -300px;
  transition: .4s;
}

#sidebar ul li {
  list-style: none;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 26px 24px;
  font-family: "Papyrus", fantasy;
}

#sidebar .toggle-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 330px;
}

.toggle-btn span {
  width: 45px;
  height: 4px;
  background: black;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

#sidebar.active {
  left: 0;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1584.86181640625;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1584.86181640625;
  animation: LineAnimation 3s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes LineAnimation {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
}

h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Trirong", serif;
}

.accordion__button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 600px;
  display: block;
  width: 10%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  transition: background 0.2s;
}

.accordion__button::after {
  content: '\25be';
  float: right;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.accordion__button--active {
  background: #333333
}

.accordion__button--active::after {
  content: '\25b4'
}

.accordion__content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 147px;
  left: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background: #333333;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<title>Website personal</title>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="talent.css" />
</head>



<div id="sidebar">
  <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="show()">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="da.html" target="_self" id="rcorners1">Acasa</a></li>
    <li><a href="cv.asp" target="_self" id="rcorners1">CV</a></li>
    <li><a href="despremine.asp" target="_self" id="rcorners1">Despre mine</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.asp" target="_self" id="rcorners1">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<body style="background-color:#222222;">
  <div class="accordion">
    <button type="button" class="accordion__button">Cine sunt eu ?</button>
    <div class="accordion__content">
      <p>Salut! Bine ai venit pe website-ul meu personal. Eu sunt Botezatu Dragos-George, student la Facultatea de Electronică, Telecomunicații și Tehnologia Informației.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="smecherie.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I've tried to find a position that doesn't disturb the sidebar when it's active but it looks bad in my opinion.

Comment: Edited your question, so it will be easier to understood. I particularly liked the șmecherie.js in your code, I wonder what fente mișto will they contain. Sorry, your joke was so good that I absolutely needed to continue it :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will need to change the `left` of both the accordion content and button to their starting position and toggle the `active` class for them. Consequently, you will need to have a rule that overrides their `left` when they are `active`. I added a `transition` too, so they move consistently.

```js
function show() {
  document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('active');
  document.querySelector(".accordion__button").classList.toggle('active');
  document.querySelector(".accordion__content").classList.toggle('active');
  
}
document.querySelectorAll('.accordion__button').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const accordionContent = button.nextElementSibling;
    button.classList.toggle('accordion__button--active');
    if (button.classList.contains('accordion__button--active')) {
      accordionContent.style.maxHeight = accordionContent.scrollHeight + 'px';

    } else {
      accordionContent.style.maxHeight = 0;
    }
  })
})
```

```css
#rcorners1 {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #222222;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  background-color: #222222;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  color: #EFDC75;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  left: -300px;
  transition: .4s;
}

#sidebar ul li {
  list-style: none;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 26px 24px;
  font-family: "Papyrus", fantasy;
}

#sidebar .toggle-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 330px;
}

.toggle-btn span {
  width: 45px;
  height: 4px;
  background: black;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

#sidebar.active {
  left: 0;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1584.86181640625;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1584.86181640625;
  animation: LineAnimation 3s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes LineAnimation {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
}

h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Trirong", serif;
}

.accordion__button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 10%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  transition: background 0.2s;
  transition: left .4s;
}

.accordion__button::after {
  content: '\25be';
  float: right;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.accordion__button--active {
  background: #333333
}

.accordion__button--active::after {
  content: '\25b4'
}

.accordion__content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 147px;
  left: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background: #333333;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: left .4s;
}

.accordion__button.active, .accordion__content.active {
    left: 310px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<title>Website personal</title>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="talent.css" />
</head>



<body style="background-color:#222222;">
<div id="sidebar">
  <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="show()">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="da.html" target="_self" id="rcorners1">Acasa</a></li>
    <li><a href="cv.asp" target="_self" id="rcorners1">CV</a></li>
    <li><a href="despremine.asp" target="_self" id="rcorners1">Despre mine</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.asp" target="_self" id="rcorners1">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
  <div class="accordion">
    <button type="button" class="accordion__button">Cine sunt eu ?</button>
    <div class="accordion__content">
      <p>Salut! Bine ai venit pe website-ul meu personal. Eu sunt Botezatu Dragos-George, student la Facultatea de Electronică, Telecomunicații și Tehnologia Informației.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="smecherie.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```